Match and delete substrings of duplicate characters and then return the length of a longest substring
I have some random string (letter-case is not matter I suppose) as an example: "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop".
I need to create a method which takes a string as the argument, then makes a new string with distinct characters only from the input string and return the length of the longest one substring made from characters which appears more than once in the input string in addition the above mentioned new string:
"aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop" —> "qwkfaslyetdop"
int resultLength = GetMaxLengthOfDuplicateSubstring("aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop", out string resultString);

Console.WriteLine($"{resultString}\nTHE LENGTH OF THE LONGEST DELETED SUBSTRING: {resultLength}");

// OUTPUT:
//
// qwkfaslyetdop
// THE LENGTH OF THE LONGEST DELETED SUBSTRING: 4

I have tried to locate a set of characters which are repeat itself.
var example = "qwasldkfaslyetdop";

var matchStrings = new string[example.Length];

var distinctStrings = new List<string>();

for (int index = 0; index < example.Length; index = index + 1)
{
    matchStrings[index] = example[index].ToString();

    if (Regex.Matches(example, matchStrings[index]).Count > 1)
    {
        distinctStrings.Add(matchStrings[index]);
    }
}

distinctStrings = distinctStrings.Distinct().ToList();

foreach (string element in distinctStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}

But due all this permutations like "a", "s", "l", "d", "as", "sa", "asl", "sal", "sla", "lsa", "als", "las", "asld", ... I just lost my initial idea how solve this problem.
I do not know why teacher from private online school made such difficult exercise, I already lost my 'deadline' with it. I have tried also positive lookaheads/lookbehinds, without much of success.

I dont know c#, but maybe: 1a) create a set of duplicate chars in the string. 1b) remove all chars out of that set from your string. 2a) create a list of 1 and 0 of the lenght of your original string; 1 if letter is in set, 0 else. 2b) then run a cummulative sum that resets to 0 when a 0 occurs (00110100111) -> (00120100123). 2c) find max of that list.

Is there any limitation on the type of characters in your string? Punctuation, spaces, non-english letters....?

You've tagged this with regex. Does that mean this problem is supposed to be solved with regex? Did you get that instruction?

In your example, why isn't it "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop" or "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop"? I don't understand why "asld" is special here.

Why do you have to use regex?

@canton7 a,s,l,d appear more than once.

@shingo If it's just removing duplicated characters, why isn't it "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop"?

@canton7 I guess it should be understood as removing excessive duplicated characters. Such as what Distinct does.

@shingo Yeah that's why I'm asking -- guessing at what the question means is never a good way forwards!

@DuesserBaest — Will not work, we just count appearence of duplication chars in the string as a whole, but we need substring where they placed nearby, as far as I understand your algorithm Mr. Baest, but I have something in my mind, got it when I was outdoor with my turkeys last hour, it is horrible inefficient in terms of computation, but I will try to implement.

@trincot
Unfortunately the teacher did not clarify anything about what chars can be in the text of the problem, as she did not clarify about permutations, so I make easier task for myself by assuming they are only letters...

@trincot
Because I have tried to solve the problem with Regex class, and for now failed. That because the tag 'regex' exist. Was I wrong?

@shingo — Now, it is not that easy. We can remove duplicates with Distinct(), it actually used in the example above, but how we can count length of corresponding substring then? We should match that substring first... And this is the big problem for me, due to permutations.

Something like this?
int GetMaxLengthOfDuplicateSubstring(string input, out string result)
{
    var seen = new HashSet<char>();
    
    int maxRemoveLength = 0;
    int currentRemoveLength = 0;
    var resultBuilder = new List<char>();
    foreach (char c in input.Reverse())
    {
        if (seen.Add(c))
        {
            currentRemoveLength = 0;
            resultBuilder.Add(c);
        }
        else
        {
            currentRemoveLength++;
            maxRemoveLength = Math.Max(maxRemoveLength, currentRemoveLength);
        }
    }
    
    result = string.Concat(resultBuilder.AsEnumerable().Reverse());
    return maxRemoveLength;
}

We go through the string backwards, making a note of every character we've seen. If we reach a character we've seen before, we remove it from the result, and keep a running tally of the number of characters we've removed in this continuous sequence.
Run online.

And how we count the length of the longest substring made from duplicate characters which stand together? Like in the example above.

We do that as shown in my code, with currentRemoveLength to track the length of the current substring being removed, and maxRemoveLength to track the maximum length of such substrings. You can see that it returns the correct value if you click the link at the bottom of my answer

In your algorithm, Mr. Canton, we count the length of substring made from deleted characters, as far as I understand, which is not the case. We need a length of substring of such chars stands together, like 'ALSAOLXAOPL' —> 'SXAOPL', LENGTH: 3 Or I missing something... O_o

Putting in "ALSAOLXAOPL" returns 3. Use the link in my question to run the code online, and then replace "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop" with "ALSAOLXAOPL" on the first line. You can see in the right-hand pane that the code returns 3

@YaroslavParkhomenko Do you follow? It's a similar cumulative count to DuessertBert's answer, but the logic to remove duplicate characters is significantly simpler

— I am starting to understand! Thank you too, Mr. Canton!

@YaroslavParkhomenko, type @ and then first letter from user name to use prompt with complete user name. Changing name and adding "Mr." in front of it is rather strange, likely just wrong.

Explanation:
1a) create a set of duplicate chars in the string.
1b) remove all chars out of that set from your string.
2a) create a list of 1 and 0 of the lenght of your original string; 1 if letter is in set, 0 else.
2b) then run a cummulative sum that resets to 0 when a 0 occurs (00110100111) -> (00120100123).
2c) find max of that list.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static Dictionary<char, int> ListToCountDict(List<char> l)
    {
        Dictionary<char, int> counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        foreach (char item in l)
        {
            if (counts.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                counts[item]++;
            }
            else
            {
                counts[item] = 1;
            }
        }
        return counts;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string str = "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop";

        var duplLetters = new HashSet<char>(ListToCountDict(str.ToList()).Where(kvp => kvp.Value > 1).Select(kvp => kvp.Key));

        string resS = new string(str.Where(s => !duplLetters.Contains(s)).ToArray());

        List<int> binaryDup = str.Select(s => duplLetters.Contains(s) ? 1 : 0).ToList();

        int max = 0;
        int cur = 0;
        foreach (int b in binaryDup)
        {
            if (b == 0)
            {
                cur = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cur += b;
            }
            if (cur > max)
            {
                max = cur;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Result String: {resS}, Max: {max}");
    }
}

Prints: Result String: qwkfyetop, Max: 4

yes, tried it at programiz

Wrong answer, because if we have 'JKLOJMK', we should obtain 'LOJMK', but not 'LOM'. Anyway thanks for the attempt... I will try to read your answer and maybe I maybe something helpful there.

abcdxabcxacxa will return 9 for the max length of the removed substring, which seems incorrect.

@YaroslavParkhomenko please clarify your question! In "JKLOJMK" duplicates are "JK" so i do expect "LOM" as the result

Yes I agree, the question is not clear. I would also expect LOM as the result from how the question is written.

@MatthewWatson why? My understanding is that all duplicates are to be removed - only d is kept. then the longes sequence is 9 : xabcxacxa

@DuesserBaest — It pretty clear in the example inside the question-post, "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop" —> "qwkfaslyetdop", should be like that.

@YaroslavParkhomenko It's very much NOT clear -- that's why there's so much confusion about it!

@YaroslavParkhomenko please EDIT your question making CLEAR, WHY "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop" —> "qwkfaslyetdop". I do not get this mapping based on your current explanation

@DuesserBaest — "All substring made from them" should be deleted, as I pointed in the question. "Them" mean duplicates, and to clarify it, I made example. I thought it is enough, but due to my low English...

@YaroslavParkhomenko "qwkfaslyetdop", just for example is based on the earlier "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop". so how could this be the solution? or what am i missing?

@DuesserBaest You are correct, I was misunderstanding the question.

@DuesserBaest
"qwkfaslyetdop" — can be solution for "aqaswasldkaslfaslyetdop" because we made a new string with distinct characters, the bold type is used for chars which appear more than once in the initial string.

@YaroslavParkhomenko I do now understand what you are looking for. If you want I can leave this aswer for you, else I will delete it, since it does not solve your issue

@DuesserBaest
No delete plz, I need to read and understand it first.

@DuesserBaest
I think the idea with commulative sum is very ingenious! At least for now I think so... So I will try to use it. Bu I never worked with commulative sums, so I do not understand how they compute, I mean for the whole list? Or for nearby elements?

@YaroslavParkhomenko you move trough the list. when you encounter 0 you reset you current count. when you encounter 1 you add 1 to you current count and check if it exeeds the previous maximum.

@DuesserBaest
Too poor I cannot choose two answers as correct. But I will use commulative sum and some logic from Mr. canton7 solution to finish this CURSED TEST! Thank you.

no worries. do not forget to also upvote @canton7 answer
